# Firebase ML Kit Exceeds GitHub's file size limit

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-mlkit

My main question is the following: is it common to have the Firebase ML Kit SDK exceed GitHub's file size limit, thus not allowing a push to the GitHub remote? Am I missing something - if so, is there a common workaround?

My issue, specifically, is the following:

`remote: error: File Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector is 265.89 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

As you can see, the `GoogleMobileVision`'s `TextDetector` framework is very large.

A few details:

1. At the moment, I am only using Text Recognition from Firebase ML Kit
2. My Podfile is as follows (taken from Firebase install docs):

   ```
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
   # If using an on-device API:
   pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'`
   ```

This app is still in development, not deployed to the App Store or anything. I am willing to use Git Large File Storage (LFS) as is suggested, just wondering if this is absolutely necessary. Seems a bit strange for everyone using this to have to take this approach.

Thank you very much in advance for any info/expertise.

UPDATE:
I contacted Firebase support; they are very responsive and sent back the following reply: "You’re right, ML Kit framework(s) could be larger than other frameworks, thus might require you to opt for Git LFS. Thanks for your feedback though, I will take note of this."

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue for a group project, and there might be a better way to do this, but we decided to include Pods/ in our .gitignore. Every time you pull you'll need to run pod install and pod update, which is kind of a pain, but it seems to work.

Comment: Hey J. Oh, thanks for the response! That sounds like a practical approach, makes sense. I was thinking that as well. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: No problem Matt! :)